# Путаница в getter и setter

Tags: java, setter, getter

Объясните пожалуйста, почему для setName пишем в аргументах (String a) a не (String name)? 
Аналогичный вопрос к (String color) - почему не (String a) и потом color = a?
Зачем такая путаница?

```
class Cat{

private String name;
private String color;

public String getName(){
  return name;
} 

public void setName(String a){
  name = a;
}

public String getColor(){
  return color;
} 

public void setColor(String color){
  this.color = color;
}

}
```

Comment: Возможно, автор этого кода решил, что скверное название параметра метода (`a`) стоит того, чтобы не заморачиваться с `this.` в теле метода. Однозначного и объективного ответа на ваш вопрос нет.

Comment: На мой взгляд, вариант `public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }` выглядит лучше. А ещё лучше выглядит вариант, в котором вообще нет "чистых" (то есть которые действительно сделаны только для установки и получения значения поля) getter и setter методов

Comment: Интересно. Странно что автор не упомянул такую важную вещь что можно и так и так написать. Но может все таки есть разница между этими вариантами и причина почему так написано...

Comment: Как по мне, лучше придерживаться подхода, который предлагает c# когда разворачивает getter и setter у свойств, а именно, использовать value в качестве имени параметра

Comment: Ресурс вроде достаточно профессиональный. vertex-academy.com и там нет этому объяснения.

Comment: @AlexeyVL мы же не можем заглянуть в голову автора. Может, он хотел продемонстрировать оба варианта. Но даже в этом случае `value` вместо `a` выглядело бы куда лучше

Comment: Это скорее всего учебный пример,  который показывает, что без уточняющей ссылки this выражение name = name может интерпретироваться  не правильно. name = name по факту означает -  параметру метода name присвоить значение параметра метода name. локальные переменные перекрывают поля экземпляра. Чтобы перекрытия не произошло, нужно уточнять переменную экземпляра с помощью ссылки this, что и показано на примере с this.color = color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соло-мини проектах можно использовать и так, но если вы участвуете в каком нибудь "Big project" то лучше называть переменные своими именами, тем более если метод принимает не один аргумент. Так людям будет проще использовать ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что имена переменных не влияют на логику программы (естественно, если выполнены синтаксические требования языка программирования и областей видимости)